# String Char Iterator

Tags: c++, iterator

Just returned to programming in C++.
the errors i get:

> request for member begin in sent is of non-class type char[30]
>
> request for member end in sent is of non-class type char[30]

```
char sent[] = "need to break this shiat down";
    for(vector<string>::iterator it=sent.begin(); it!=sent.end(); ++it){
        if(*it == " ")
            cout << "\n";
        else
            cout << *it << endl;
    }
```

should i change the char to string or define the vector differently?

Comment: Wrong var declaration, should be char[] sent = "need to break this shiat down"

Comment: @imulsion the declaration is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use streaming to throw out the whitespace and throw in newlines.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    stringstream ss("need to break this shiat down.", ios_base::in);

    string s;
    while (ss >> s)
        cout << s << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Result:

> need
>   to
>   break
>   this
>   shiat
>   down.

Comment: Looks like the simplest solution for splitting on " " (spaces).

Answer (score 4):

It has been pointed out in other answers that you are iterating over the wrong type. You should define `sent` to be of `std::string` type and use `std::string::begin()` and `std::string::end()` to iterate, or, if you have C++11 support, you have some options for easily iterating over a fixed size array. You can iterate using `std::begin` and std::end`:

```
char sent[] = "need to break this shiat down";
for(char* it = std::begin(sent); it != std::end(sent); ++it){
    if(*it == ' ')
        std::cout << "\n";
    else
        std::cout << *it << "\n";
}
```

or you can use a range-based loop:

```
char sent[] = "need to break this shiat down";
for (const auto& c : sent)
{
  std::cout << c << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`char sent[]` is not `std::string` but string literal - but in this very case you can iterate over it:

```
int main() {
char sent[] = "need to break this shiat down";
    for(auto it = std::begin(sent); it!=std::end(sent) - 1; ++it){
        if(*it == ' ')
            cout << "\n";
        else
            cout << *it << endl;
    }
}
```

Note that I changed `" "` to `' '` - and skipped last null terminating char `'\0'`...

Live example: http://liveworkspace.org/code/55f826dfcf1903329c0f6f4e40682a12

For C++03 you can use this approach:

```
int main() {
char sent[] = "need to break this shiat down";
    for(char* it = sent; it!=sent+sizeof(sent) - 1; ++it){
        if(*it == ' ')
            cout << "\n";
        else
            cout << *it << endl;
    }
}
```

If this is string literal of size not known at that point - use strlen instead of sizeof...

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `sent` is not of type `vector<string>`, but `char[]`.

Your for loop however, tries to iterate over a **vector of strings**.

For a plain array, use C iteration:

```
 int len = strlen(sent);
 for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `string` instead of `char[]`

```
string sent = "need to break this shiat down";
for(string::iterator it=sent.begin(); it!=sent.end(); ++it){
    if(*it == ' ')
        cout << "\n";
    else
        cout << *it << endl;
}
```

`char[]` doesnt have begin and end methods..